# PC controller issue: D-pad affects X-rotation

Tags: pc, controllers, hardware

Recently, I discovered an issue with my PC controller(namely, Redgear Pro Wireless gamepad). Whenever I move forward in a game(left thumb stick up), the direction changes to the left and whenever I move backwards(left thumb stick down), direction changes to the right. So basically I move forward and left simultaneously, backwards and right simultaneously. The left thumb stick seems to be linked with the right thumb stick(which governs the direction of movement in most video games). Sometimes the controller works properly but most of the times it has this issue. The following screen shot of the game controller settings shows the problem in detail:

Controller Untouched:
[image]

When the left thumb stick up(notice how it affects the X-axis):
[image]

When the left thumb stick is down:
[image]

Now I thought this was a software issue, so I tried my controller in some other PC and unfortunately, I'm having the exact same issue. This seems to indicate that the issue is with the controller itself(i.e hardware issue). This has been bugging me for a while. I've tried to articulate my issue in the best way possible hoping that someone can provide a viable solution(I do not wish to purchase a new controller). In conclusion: please help!

Comment: Redgear Pro Wireless supports two modes: XInput and DirectInput. Do you know which mode you're in when you have this issue, and have you tried switching to the other mode? Also, Windows has a gamepad calibration tool. Have you tried using it?

Comment: @nondebug I've no idea what you're talking about. Can explain how to switch the modes?

Comment: See the user manual here: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81-ZT2lO1eS.pdf Page 1, Operating Instructions, Mode switch: "Hold the HOME key about 5 seconds, to switch the mode between Xinput, DirectInput"  XInput and DirectInput are two different standards for gamepads. Some apps are compatible with both, some require one or the other.

Comment: I've tried it, doesn't fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

The most generic of answers will be to ensure your [drivers](https://redwoodinteractive.net/drivers/) are up to date for the device.

It also sounds like that is how the device is sending the signal to your machine. So you will have to do some other kind of input changing. You'll have to map the directions in your game or you will need an application like [JoyToKey](https://joytokey.net/en/) to change the default mapping of your device to how you want the inputs to be handled.

Answer (score 1):

I am having this same issue with an almost brand new controller. I found the problem to be a short within the controller. The left joystick should not move the X or Y axis, so it has to be a short within the controller. I tried my older controller and the two joystick inputs are no longer combined. It is intermittent for me, so it was a little tricky to figure out at first.